# Listen to file modification and identify newly added lines in java

Tags: java, file-io, listener, event-listener

I'm building a library (java 8) that needs to listen to the modifications of several files. The library needs parse the newly added lines in the corresponding files each time a modification occurs.

The files are like event logs. So they are always appended (no deletion or overriding)

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to know what are the newly added lines in a file when its modified? (is there a functionality in java NIO to identify this?)
2. I've seen solutions in NIO package (Watch Service API) that can be used as poll based mechanism to listen to file modification. Is there another native solution to make it push based? so that I don't need to keep polling between intervals of time.

I'm mainly looking for a native solution but third party solution suggestion are also appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You implement "push" by running a `take()` loop in its own thread. On each `take()` you start a new thread to process the changed lines.

To determine what changed, keep track of the file length each time... Changed data is at offset `previousSize` for length `newSize - previousSize`.

You'll probably want some kind of event coordination to prevent starting the process again before the previous instance completes.  That could happen if there are multiple changes in a very short period of time.